# keydown to trigger the css change of <a>, open a link in new tab, and rollback to the previous css status of <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I am working on a small site in which once a key is pressed in the keyboard, the following three would happen sequentially
1) the corresponding  changes its css
2) a link is opened in a new tab
3) the corresponding  rollbacks to the previous css status

Here is the css.

```
div.website a:link, div.website a:visited{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:45px;
    height:45px;
    font-size:14px;
    border-radius:2px;
    color:#474a4d;
    transition-property:background-color, color, font-size;
    transition-duration:0.2s;
    transition-timing-function:ease;
  }
  div.website a:hover{
    background-color:#2c3e50;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:24px;
  }
```

Here is the code

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var k = event.which || event.keyCode;
      for(var i = 32; i < 91; i++){
        if (i == k){
          var obj = $("a.hotkey" + k);
          obj.animate({
            fontSize:"24px"
          },{
            duration:500,
            complete:function(){
              setTimeout(function(){
                window.open(obj.attr("href"));
              },500);
            }
          });
          obj.animate({
            fontSize:"14px"
          });
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
```

Here is the html code

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 website">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="11" class="website hotkey66 hotkey32" target="_blank">
    <span>facebook</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

However, when the code is executed(when I actually pressed the key), it seems that the 1) and 3) are executing in the same time, not sequentially, there is no css change of the . Then I undertook the debugging mode in Chrome, and it confirmed my guess.

In addition, actually I want the  to be on a hovering effect, but later I changed it to only the font-size change. If someone could tell me how to simulate the hovering effect and rollback, it would be so much appreciating. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shot.  Instead of using `jQuery.animate' just use your CSS transitions.

On keypress, add the 'hover' class to the element, then remove it when you trigger the new page.  Also add the 'hover' rules to the css.

```js
$(document).bind("keydown", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var k = event.which || event.keyCode;
  for(var i = 32; i < 91; i++){
    if (i == k){
      var obj = $("a.hotkey" + k);
      obj.addClass('hover')
      setTimeout(function(){
        window.open(obj.attr("href"));
        obj.removeClass('hover')
      },500);
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
div.website a:link, div.website a:visited{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-decoration:none;
  line-height:45px;
  height:45px;
  font-size:14px;
  border-radius:2px;
  color:#474a4d;
  transition-property:background-color, color, font-size;
  transition-duration:0.2s;
  transition-timing-function:ease;
}
div.website a.hover,
div.website a:hover{
  background-color:#2c3e50;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 website">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="11" class="website hotkey66 hotkey32" target="_blank">
    <span>facebook</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

You'll notice that facebook doesn't start up from Stack, but that's because the sandboxed environment doesn't allow popups.  I tried the same in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/wBzbwP) and it seems to work just fine.  Give it a shot and let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: It worked really! Thanks so much! I tried animate for a whole day and it didn't work. What you did reminds me there might always be some other way. ^_^